# jQuery / JS Links are not working randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My issue is pretty stupid and easily fixable I guess. But well, I'm looking for the reason since some hours, and didn't find it.

Here is the link: https://nnsprod.com/naheulbeuk/Maps.php

Try to navigate on the map (this part working), but randomly, the Previous Arrow (top left corner) isn't working.

I thought it was du to some z-index or whatever, but not. Seems to be something else. And to be clear, I have try a JS link (like now, with onclick) and also a direct a tag. Same issue.

Someone see something ?

Thanks :)

Edit: Lack of code, sorry about that.
Full code in disponible via a simple see source. Everything is on JS.

I generate the link via this :

```css
.controls {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  z-index:20;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
 <a href="javascript:history.back()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: We'll need more information if you want us to help. How do you bind the links? Do you have an example of your code?

Comment: Please provide the shortest (minimal) code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please read [ask] and especially [mcve]. Provide a minimal but complete set of code **in the question itself** so that we can help you.

Comment: Edited the post. Sorry about that... (>°_°)>

Comment: I ran your page and I wasn't able to duplicate your error but I am seeing a mixed content error in the console.  I thought perhaps it was with font-awesome but no, it's with `Open Sans` being loaded over `http` instead of `https`.  It might not address your problem but should be corrected anyway.

Comment: Ow, thanks, I will correct this !
And yes, the error is randomly. Around 1/3 times.

Comment: Someone had see the problem? Even without correct it. Is it appear only to me ? ;) Click on "Mliuej" city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me with Chrome 64.0.3 the `javascript:history.back()` links did not work at all. But this version worked fine though:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="history.back()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
```

Comment: Damn, it's working. Very strange that some pages were working, and other not. Thanks a lot !